# add serial id to content type

Tags: 7, nodes

How do I add a NUMBER field to my content type?
A NUMBER field means a serial id similar to auto incremented primary key on a DB table.
I wanna use a unique NUMBER in view related to my content.

Comment: All entities, including content, already has a serial numeric id.

Comment: Are you creating the content type via code or via drupal cms interface? nid, is already of type serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Serial](http://drupal.org/project/serial) module will be helpful for you.

> This module provides an auto-increment (serial) field.
>
> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are managed per content type (D6)/entity (D7). For example, the serial field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.

Comment: When reading that module page, I'm interested in Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID. How do I use such built-in ID as a filed?

Comment: Please tell Which type of view you r creating.You can simply add the nid field.

Comment: I created a new content type with some text fields and photo field. I'm interested in that nid field. Please show me how to add it.

Comment: You should click on the fields in the view and select the node field group. and select the nid as field.So simple.

Comment: I chose to use the serial module in accordance with your advice eventually.